# Error with cor.test, results display the following...not enough finite observations

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to run a correlation test. Instead I am getting the following error.

**Error in cor.test.default(Indicator, Revpolu) : 
  not enough finite observations**  What does this mean?

The script stops at **table_corr <- setDT(table)[, list(Revpolu, Indicator), by = list(Club, Date)]**

The **table_corr** variable is storing 1161 observations of 4 variables.

```
library(data.table)

dat <- read.csv("corrtest.csv", header = TRUE)

dat$Date <- as.Date(paste0(format(strptime(as.character(dat$Date), 
                                       "%m/%d/%y"), 
                              "%Y/%m"),"/1"))

table <- (setDT(dat)[, list(Revenue = sum(Revenues),
                               Hours = sum(Hours),
                               Indicator = mean(Indicator)), 
                        by = list(Club, Date)])

table$Hours[table$Hours == 0 ] <-NA

table <- table[complete.cases(table), ]

table[, Revpolu := Revenue / Hours]

table_corr <- setDT(table)[, list(Revpolu, Indicator), 
                              by = list(Club, Date)]

testing <- table_corr[, list(Correlation = cor.test(Indicator, Revpolu)[["estimate"]]), 
                        by = Club]

testing <- testing[complete.cases(testing), ] 

correl <- testing[, round(Correlation, digits = 2)]

done <- round(mean(correl), digits = 2)
```

Comment: I think the error is quite self-explaining. Are there NAs in the dataset? Have you checked how many non-NA values are there per Club? Or how many observations there are per Club?

Comment: There were 0's and to eliminate the zero's I replaced them with NA's and then ran complete.cases to eliminate the rows that had NA's. How do I check for non-NA values? I may be missing something very obvious here. Do you mean check for how many observations there is per club before running the script or afterwards?